# ADO - WIQL - How to query ADO workitems for reporting developer productivity and quality

Tags: azure-devops, reporting, dashboard, wiql

I am looking to drive objective metrics from ADO like reopened bugs by a developer, number of bugs against user story.  In a collaborative environment, there are high chances the developer fixing a bug that has been raised against a user story that was completed by another developer.  Would like to filter work items to identify productivity and quality for each developer.

Not sure how to extend this to filter:

```
SELECT System.Id],[System.WorkItemType],[System.Title],[System.State],
  [System.AreaPath],[System.IterationPath] FROM workitems WHERE 
  [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' AND 
  [System.Id] = '84019' ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Those are *not* good metrics for measuring productivity or work quality.